# Typescript problem to loop through an array of tuple and get specific values

Tags: typescript

I have to write a function that takes an array of tuples, each tuple consists of a name and an age. The function should return only the names.

So I wrote it like this:

```
type someTuple = [string, number]

function names(namesAndAges: someTuple[]) {
  let allNames: string[]
  allNames.push(namesAndAges.forEach( nameAndAge => nameAndAge[0]))
  
  return allNames
}
```

When I call it with this:

```
names([['Amir', 34], ['Betty', 17]]);
```

I get this error:

```
type error: type error: Variable 'allNames' is used before being assigned.
```

Can anyone point what is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't declare `allNames` to be an array, so change it to this:

```
let allNames: string[] = []
```

If you want to get all name in an array your function should be like this:

```
type someTuple = [string, number]

function names(namesAndAges: someTuple[]) {
  let allNames: string[] = []
  namesAndAges.forEach( nameAndAge => 
    allNames.push(nameAndAge[0])
  )
  return allNames
}

names([['Amir', 34], ['Betty', 17]]);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=12&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAzg9gWwgFQK5gDbQLxQNozABOAlgHYDmANFGaggEYREC6AUGwGapkDGwJOGVoBDJDAAUZMRBgBBMgBM5FWQC5YiFOix4WASigBvNlChZgUERgwA5GTA2FSlPVFx7To8QuWqYAHSccEQAoiK8ABYS3hC%20KjgAfFBeZtZ2DgFgqDDR0kjxqngADAZe%20l5EEMCoRMLp9uJsAL4cvELwWAEYcBRSDhJ4eADkcggkRMM0AMwALCw0IwBC1aBTUACMAOwsBvoA3GxAA)

Comment: Thank you, I was forgetting this. Now I'm getting this error: type error: Argument of type 'void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Comment: Happy to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `.map` here for a better code readability

```js
function names(namesAndAges: [string, number][]): string[] {
  return namesAndAges.map(nameAndAge => nameAndAge[0]);
}

names([['Amir', 34], ['Betty', 17]]);
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABGAhgWwKYGcAUrNYCCYAJoQObYBciA2llAE4xjkA0yIaARhowLq1%20AShoNmrIYgDeAKESJGGKCEZJ82YmUpYAdGhQAHPOgxaKGRAF4AfMlPnKtAAwiA3LIC%20s2RARY4ABsMXUC4chMCHFpaAHJCNBhGWI4AZgAWfg44gCFlKABPFMQARgB2fhFhDyA)